# QGridLayout остаются серые полоски pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qt-designer, qgridlayout

В коде у меня *при нажатии на серую кнопку* открывается *желтый* `gridlayout`, но проблема в том, что с лева и наверху остаются серенькие полоски.

Кк это исправить? Провозился пол часа с этим, но ничего не вышло.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1130, 460)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 129))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("label---", self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("label---")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("pushButton---", self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

#        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))               # -
        self.pushButton.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))                  # +++

        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 15px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);")
        self.pushButton.setText("")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 3, 0, 2, 2)              # -+
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(25)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Окно в окне"))


class Ui_MainWindow_2(object):                                          # Ui_MainWindow_2
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1140, 460)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1140, 460))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(25)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Окно которое должно открываться после нажатия на кнопку"))

class ExampleApp2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow_2):               # Ui_MainWindow_2
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)


class ExampleApp1(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def  onClicked(self):
        self.exampleApp2 = ExampleApp2()
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.exampleApp2, 0, 0, 2, 1)


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp1()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... проблема в том, что с лева и наверху остаются серенькие полоски ...

1. Ни в этом проблема, **раскройте ваше окно на весь экран и нажмите кнопку.** Вот те на, просто чудеса.
2. С другой стороны, я в предыдущем ответа сбрасывал вам ссылку, как правильно сделать.
3. Теперь об исправленном примере:

   - Вы не должны ничего рисовать 'сверху'.
   - Вам надо очистить `gridLayout` и наполнить его новым содержимым.

---

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1130, 460)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(200, 129))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("label---", self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("1 - label---")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton("1 - pushButton---", self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)

#        self.pushButton.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))               # -
        self.pushButton.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(30, 30))                  # +++

        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 15px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(70, 70, 70);")
        self.pushButton.setText("1B")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton, 3, 0, 2, 2)              # -+
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(25)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1 - Окно"))


class Ui_MainWindow_2(object):                                          # Ui_MainWindow_2
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1140, 460)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(1140, 460))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(16777215, 16777215))
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: yellow")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.centralwidget.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.centralwidget.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setText("2 - label")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(25)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2 - Окно которое должно открываться после нажатия на кнопку"))

class ExampleApp2(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow_2):               # Ui_MainWindow_2
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)


class ExampleApp1(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def  onClicked(self):
        self.exampleApp2 = ExampleApp2()

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        countLayout = self.gridLayout.count()   
        for it in range(countLayout):             
            w = self.gridLayout.itemAt(0).widget()
            self.gridLayout.removeWidget(w)               
            w.hide()

        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.exampleApp2, 0, 0, 2, 1)
# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp1()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]